# Spark Scala Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Launching spark-submit I'm getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection

Spark Code Class 1:

```
var vertices = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/cloudera/dstlf.txt")
  .flatMap { line => line.split("\\s+") }
  .distinct()

vertices.map { 
  vertex => vertex.replace("-", "") + "\t" + vertex.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///user/cloudera/metadata-lookup-tlf")
}
```

Spark Code Class 2:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,"hdfs:///user/cloudera/metadata-processed-tlf")

// Run PageRank
val ranks = graph.pageRank(0.0001).vertices
```

Looks like for some reason it is not working in the RDD

The input file `dstlf` contains 2 columns with numbers:

```
94-92250 94-92174
94-92889 94-91869
94-94172 94-91682
...
```

Comment: Apparently there is an empty RDD somewhere in your code. Can you share the code around your call to `pageRank`?

Comment: val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "metadata-processed-tlf")

    // Run PageRank

    val ranks = graph.pageRank(0.0001).vertices

    val entities = sc.textFile("metadata-lookup-tlf").map
    {
      line =>val fields = line.split("\\s+")
       (fields(0).toLong, fields(1))
    }

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the "metadata-processed-tlf" file

Comment: looks like is not writing out the results to the hdfs.I have tried, modifying by    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,"hdfs:///user/cloudera/metadata-processed-tlf") but still the issue persists

Comment: I suggest you add to your question: 1) a sample of this file and  2) a part of the code around the pageRank call which raises the error